# Tricky combinatorics problem

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

> You get $15$ free spins on a slot machine, with a $0.01$ chance of re-triggering a further $15$ spins when a certain symbol falls on the centre reel. You can keep re-triggering a further $15$ spins, but it's capped at a maximum of $180$ spins. I'm trying to work out the expected number of spins.

I'm aware that if there are unlimited re-triggers I can use the generating function $\frac{1}{(1-np)}$ and multiply this by the initial number of free spins to get $17.65$ total expected spins.

I'm really struggling to find the correct way to limit this to $180$ spins though ($11$ re-triggers). The problem is that the number of ways you can hit $X$ re-triggers grows extremely quickly.

For example, if we think of this in terms of blocks of $15$ free spins, for two re-triggers we could either hit both in the first block of $15$ then no more, or one in the first block and one in the second block. I'll denote this as $200$ or $110$.

For three re-triggers, we can have $3000$, $2100$, $2010$, $1200$, $1110$. Note that we can't have $1020$ as we wouldn't get to the third block of $15$ spins.

But then within each of these five ways, there are different combinations to get them. So $3000$ has $C(15,3)$, $2100$ has $C(15,2)×C(15,1)$, etc.

These numbers escalate very quickly and I'm not sure what series I'm looking at. It looks like Catalan numbers and Motzkin numbers may have something to do with this, but I'm not familiar with them and can't figure it out.

If anyone knows how to work out this problem, please help!

Thanks,

Martin

Comment: In a real game I would just change slot-machine(at certain point) to another one where probability to win next free spins is much less than 0.01.